# How to use Android-Libs in JUnit-Test Cases?

Tags: android

I want to use JUNIT for some network classes in my Android-Project. I am using Apache HttpClient which is already included in android. But when I run my junit test it comes to an exception. I included all my lib files in the Junit-Testrunner. But obviously it is not enough because the HttpClient is not found. Does some know what I am doing wrong?

Here is the exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient
at de.srs.android.pdixuploader.network.test.ClientAppTest.testCheckLogin(ClientAppTest.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 19 more

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding the JUnit library to my project:

- Open project's Properties > Java Build Path
- Open the Libraries tab
- Click Add Library
- Select JUnit
- Click Next
- Make sure that the correct version of JUnit is selected in the dropdown
- Click Finish